# How to get string into URL AngularJS to GET weather data

Tags: angularjs, json, string, url, get

I want to send the data (string) to a URL, so I could receive the weather of that location.

The console.log writes the correct location, without spaces.
When I paste this location into the OpenWeatherMap URL, the right data is shown.

Apart, both functions work. But together I encounter problems.

How do I solve this?
Should use a new Controller?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wouc9.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should launch the second http request in the then() call of the first one?

If you don't (like it is the case), you locationDataWithoutSpaces variable is undefined as the then() call is done **asynchronously**.

Comment: Nice! That's quickly fixed.